# TypeError: drop() got multiple values for argument 'axis' when dropping multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe called "tips" in which I am trying to drop two columns, `tip` and `higher_than_15pct_true`, as follows:

```
X = tips.drop('tip','higher_than_15pct_True', axis = 1)
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: drop() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the pandas [documentation for `DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), you need to pass either a single label, or a list if you have multiple columns:

```
X = tips.drop(['tip','higher_than_15pct_True'], axis = 1)
```

The `TypeError` unfortunately ends up being quite cryptic and unrelated to the real problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You forget the bracket.
Or use this one

```
remove = ['tip','higher_than_15pct_True']
tips= df[df.columns.difference(remove)]
```

Thanks